# access to request object when using spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

When logging in I want to read the URL and base on the combination of subdomain, username and password user should be authorized.

like if the url is abc.xyz.com

i somehow need request object to get the subdomain and authorize user using the subdomain and username.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check those items during login by creating your own `PreAuthenticated` filter and add it to the Spring Security Filter Chain.  The filter contains the method `getPreAuthenticatedPrinciple(HttpServletRequest request)` where you can see the request and act accordingly.  If you want to make the check after the user has already been authenticated then simply subclass the base `SpringSecurityFilter` and add it to the filter chain after the authentication step.

Comment: Hi Gandalf, thanks for the answer, i'll definitely check out what you suggested and mark the answer as correct once done.